# is it possible to export fields in a custom order for inheriting classe?

Tags: java, json, gson

I am using Gson to export a simple java data structure to a json file.

I have two classes defined as follow:

```java
public abstract class foo{
    @Expose()
    String name;
    //.... 
}

public class bar extends foo{
    @Expose()
    String value;
    //.... 
}
```

my export procedure is the following:

```java
public static void exportObjectToJson(Object obj, final String path) {
        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        Gson gson = builder.setPrettyPrinting().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
        FileWriter writer;
        try {
            writer = new FileWriter(path);
            writer.write(gson.toJson(obj));
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

by exporting an istance of `bar` my output will look as follow:

```json
{
    "value":"myValue",
    "name":"myName",
    ...
}
```

It looks like that the fields of the supertype of a class (`foo`) are always placed after the fields belonging to the inheriting class (`bar`).

Is there a way to configure gson so that it puts the supertype fields firts?

Or at least a way to decide which is the order of the fields?

The output I would like to have:

```json
{
    "name":"myName",
    "value":"myValue",
    ...
}
```

Thanks in advance

Dylan

Comment: Note that a JSON object is inherently unordered according to the JSON spec: other things that parse/interpret the json object are free to reorder it (and often will in the case of a Hashmap backing the object).

Comment: There exists [this open feature request](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/2309) for this. Out of curiosity, why is the field order important for your use case?

Comment: @Marcono1234 In my use case the order is important because the json I'm exporting should be readable by the user. since I am exposing a view on a data structure having the fields that are used to identify an object at the bottom makes it hard to read.